# Toggling Icons in a List

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list as defined here http://jsfiddle.net/NNFEh/7/

Here's a snapshot:

```
<ul id="Boss">
    <li class="B">Beverages
        <ul>
            <li class="C">Hot
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Medswer</a>
            </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
```

I am trying to add a +/- icon to all parent nodes i.e those that have a class=B, class=C. Please see the CSS class at http://jsfiddle.net/NNFEh/7/ where I have set the icon to a CSS sprite

Initially the two parent nodes (with class=B) should have a "+". When the user clicks on any of this parent node, it should change to "-" and toggle and so on.

How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **What have you tried so far?** If you can demonstrate what efforts you have made to solve this on your own you much more likely to get suitable responses.

Comment: Please edit your fiddle to include fully-qualified URLs to the images so they actually appear.

Comment: @Paulie_D fair enough. I have updated my post with the new fiddle

Comment: placehold.it works well for that, and there are others.

Comment: @Diodeus where do I host the image?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your icon class is not set. Then, you need to toggle between both class

```
$(function () {
    $('#Boss ul').hide();//Hide everything
    $('#Boss li').addClass('icon'); //Add the common class
    $('#Boss li').addClass('closed'); //Add the class of the toggle to closed
    $('#Boss li').on('click', function (e) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle() //Open/Close
        $(this).toggleClass( "opened" ); //If it's open, it will remove the class or add it
        $(this).toggleClass( "closed" ); //If it's closed, it will remove the class, or ad it
    });
});
```